# Как убрать лишнюю букву

Tags: java

У меня программа которая конвертирует кириллицу в латиницу.
Я хочу перевести слово "компьютер" на латинский. Он должен выдать - kompıýter, а почему конвертирует вот так с мягким знаком - kompьıýter. В латинском нету мягкого знака. Как можно исправить ошибку

вот мой код

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;

        public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {
        final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "utf-8";

        if(args.length < 2 || args.length > 3) {
            System.out.println("Неверное количество аргументов");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String inputFilePath = args[0];
        String outputFilePath = args[1];    
        String fileEncoding = args.length == 2 ? DEFAULT_ENCODING : args[2];







        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath), fileEncoding));
        File file = new File(outputFilePath);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String line;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Map<String, String> dictionary = new Dictionary().getDictionary();

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String outLine = convertString(line, dictionary) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(outLine);
            result.append(outLine) ;
        }

        writer.write(result.toString());

        in.close();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        }


    public static String convertString(String str, Map<String, String> dictionary) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (dictionary.containsKey(Character.toString(chars[i]))) {
                stringBuilder.append(dictionary.get(Character.toString(chars[i])));
                continue;
            }
            stringBuilder.append(chars[i]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}

class Dictionary {
    private Map<String, String> dictionary;

    public Dictionary() {
        dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        dictionary.put("а", "a");
        dictionary.put("А", "A");
        dictionary.put("ә", "á");
        dictionary.put("Ә", "Á");
        dictionary.put("б", "b");
        dictionary.put("Б", "B");
        dictionary.put("д", "d");
        dictionary.put("Д", "D");
        dictionary.put("е", "e");
        dictionary.put("E", "E");
        dictionary.put("ф", "f");
        dictionary.put("Ф", "F");
        dictionary.put("г", "g");
        dictionary.put("Г", "G");
        dictionary.put("ғ", "ǵ");
        dictionary.put("Ғ", "Ǵ");        
        dictionary.put("х", "h");
        dictionary.put("Х", "H");
        dictionary.put("һ", "һ");
        dictionary.put("Һ", "Һ");
        dictionary.put("і", "і");
        dictionary.put("І", "I");
        dictionary.put("и", "ı");
        dictionary.put("И", "I");
        dictionary.put("й", "ı");
        dictionary.put("Й", "I");
        dictionary.put("ж", "j");
        dictionary.put("Ж", "J");
        dictionary.put("к", "k");
        dictionary.put("К", "К");
        dictionary.put("л", "l");
        dictionary.put("Л", "L");
        dictionary.put("м", "m");
        dictionary.put("М", "M");
        dictionary.put("н", "n");
        dictionary.put("Н", "N");
        dictionary.put("ң", "ń");
        dictionary.put("Ң", "Ń");
        dictionary.put("о", "o");
        dictionary.put("О", "O");
        dictionary.put("ө", "ó");
        dictionary.put("Ө", "Ó");
        dictionary.put("п", "p");
        dictionary.put("П", "P");
        dictionary.put("қ", "q");
        dictionary.put("Қ", "Q");
        dictionary.put("р", "r");
        dictionary.put("Р", "R");
        dictionary.put("с", "s");
        dictionary.put("С", "S");
        dictionary.put("ш", "sh");
        dictionary.put("Ш", "Sh");
        dictionary.put("ч", "ch");
        dictionary.put("Ч", "Ch");
        dictionary.put("т", "t");
        dictionary.put("Т", "T");
        dictionary.put("ү", "ú");
        dictionary.put("Ү", "Ú");
        dictionary.put("ұ", "u");
        dictionary.put("Ұ", "U");
        dictionary.put("в", "v");
        dictionary.put("В", "V");
        dictionary.put("ы", "y");
        dictionary.put("Ы", "Y");
        dictionary.put("у", "ý");
        dictionary.put("У", "Ý");
        dictionary.put("з", "z");
        dictionary.put("З", "Z");
        dictionary.put("э", "e");
        dictionary.put("Э", "E");
        dictionary.put("ю", "ıý");
        dictionary.put("Ю", "Iý");
        dictionary.put("я", "ıa");
        dictionary.put("Я", "Ia");

    }

    public Map<String, String> getDictionary() {
        return dictionary;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем в словарь:

```
dictionary.put("ь", "");
dictionary.put("Ь", "");
```

Comment: kompııýter выходит не правильно (получается два "ı") а нужно kompıýetr

Comment: @АдильКабдыгазинов, Подкорректировал. У Вас в словаре "ю" переводится, как "ıý". В таком случае, "ь" просто убираем.